# Is Waterline ORM thread safe by design?

Tags: node.js, orm, thread-safety, waterline

Is waterline ORM thread safe? Or should we implement a singleton data-layer above it in our app to achieve thread safety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Node clusters, every cluster is an independent process, so every cluster has already its own memory that is not shared with other clusters.
If you have some critical sections to lock ,you should lock them using a cross-process semaphore library like *redis-mutex-semaphore* or *live-mutex* (Not tested on windows).
Note that many of distributed semaphore librairies relay on a third party like redis for *redis-mutex-semaphore* library.

Comment: I am sorry, but i asked about waterline.

Comment: I think that it's not a waterline issue, if you are using node clusters, it's up to you to manage critical sections.

Comment: i am not using clusters. So do you think waterline in thread safe without clusters?

Comment: Node is single threaded, but it uses background threads to run I/O asycnhronous tasks, so you may want to lock some logic, if so, you can use a mutex librairy